# how to copy files with a certain extension to a directory, in which the file extension and destination is being read from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, sh

I'm trying to create a script where it reads the file extension type and destination from a text file, then copies the files with that extension to destination stated in the text file

I have tried this, but if the directory doesn't exist how do I make it in the script

```
echo "Please enter name of file"
read name
while read line
do
    filetype=${line%,*}
    dest=${line#*,}
    find -iname "$filetype" -exec cp -n '{}' "$dest" \;
done < $name
```

text file

```
.txt,/home/username/Desktop/dest
```

this line appears when I run the script in the terminal

> cp: './2/sometextfile.txt' and /home/username/Desktop/2/sometextfile.txt' are the same file

Comment: You can save some trouble with `while IFS=, read filetype dest; do ...`

Comment: If you need `$dest` to exist, just add `mkdir -p "$dest"`

Comment: Maybe you are copying it to the same folder?

Comment: that find `-iname` test doesn't look like it should ever match